# What is Metropolis Skyport?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, all-star-superman

[image: "That was Metropolis Skyport: our ride to Poiseidonis has been grounded thanks to giant talking lizards and scalding steam clouds in the midtown area // I should have known there was going to be trouble when Clark Kent wangled his way out of this birthday party farce. // I swear that man can smell trouble."]

What does Cat Gram from *All-Star Superman* mean by saying "that was Metropolis Skyport"?
What’s Metropolis Skyport?
What did she mean by "our ride to Poiseidonis has been grounded"?

Comment: I think you'll have a better time getting this answered if you clean up the typos and grammar errors.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the terms that you may be confused by:

- Metropolis: The city that Superman is based out of
- Skyport: [A synonym for heliport](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skyport) (i.e. an airport for helicopters)
- Poseidonis: The [capital of Atlantis](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Poseidonis) in DC Comics
- Grounded: Not permitted to fly

Given the context of the scene, she is basically saying this:

> I just heard from the Metropolis Skyport: our helicopter ride to Poseidonis, the capital of Atlantis, is no longer permitted to fly, thanks to giant talking lizards and scalding steam clouds in the mid-town area.

Answer (score 2):

She just got of the phone/radio/whatever with the Metropolis Skyport.  Whoever she's talking to was intending to get a flight from the Skyport to Poseidonis (a mythical city, often taken to the capital of Atlantis, but apparently real in DC continuity).  The intended flight will not be taking place, however, due to the listed problems (giant lizards and scalding steam).  So they are stuck in Metropolis, since their flight isn't happening.

Comment: Poseidonis is [definitely real in DC Comics](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Poseidonis).

Comment: @Thunderforge Oh, I figured it must be.  I was a bit puzzled how you would *fly* to the capital of Atlantis though.

Comment: Presumably they would be flying to somewhere near there, then switching to some sort of underwater vehicle. Atlantis has visitors all the time in DC Comics. It would be the same if they took a boat there, but flying is faster.

Comment: Understood.But what kind of device she’s holding? Radio or celular ?